# When you close a milestone on Github what happens to open issues?

Tags: github, milestone

[image: Screenshot of a milestone with some open issues (on Github Milestones page)]

If I have a milestone with 6 open issues and 5 closed ones, what happens to those 6 open issues if I close the milestone?

Answer (score 3):

I've discovered the answer is: **nothing**

The issues are unaffected. They are still open and still associated with the now-closed milestone.

You can go to Milestones, show closed milestones, and select the milestone you closed. You then see a list of all the open issues associated with it.